# AWS Step Functions Consuming messages from SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

I am consuming messages from SQS to trigger queries.
When I normally consume a message from SQS in Python, I need to delete the message from SQS.
Do I have to manually delete the message from SQS in a Step Function?
What is the best/simplest way to do so?

I believe SQS has done the integration:

```
{
  "Comment": "Run Redshift Queries",
  "StartAt": "ReceiveMessage from SQS",
  "States": {
    "ReceiveMessage from SQS": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "QueueUrl": "******"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sqs:receiveMessage",
      "Next": "Run Analysis Queries",
      "ResultSelector": {
        "body.$": "States.StringToJson($.Messages[0].Body)"
      }
    },
    "Run Analysis Queries": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "ClusterIdentifier": "******",
        "Database": "prod",
        "Sql": "select * from ******"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:redshiftdata:executeStatement",
      "End": true
    }
  },
  "TimeoutSeconds": 3600
}
```

I just did a test and it seems that the messages goes down temporarily but then goes up again.

Is the best way to insert a Lambda in between the "ReceiveMessage from SQS" stage & Redshift stage?

This raised another question. I have only run this manually. How do I activate this Step Function eventually to run on any message?

Comment: If *you* perform a receive message call then you need to take care of deleting the message, if AWS does the sqs integration for you then you do not need to delete the messages manually.

Comment: How are you 'consuming' the messages in Step Functions?

Comment: I posted additional info to answer these questions. See above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use SQS, then you will need to have a lambda function to act as a proxy. You will need to set up the queue as a lambda trigger, and you will need to write a lambda that can parse the SQS message and make the appropriate call to the Step Functions StartExecution API.

Comment: I used the SQS trigger to Invoke a Lambda and get the proper info from the message to further parse the message body and delete the message from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

After you consume a message, you have to delete it using `sqs:deleteMessage`. The reason you see it reappear in the queue is because once it's read by an application it becomes hidden for ~30 seconds to avoid other applications process it simultaneously.

Here is an example of how to read, process and delete a message from the queue. Mind that I added `MaxNumberOfMessages` equals `1` and a `ResultPath` different than `$`

```
"ReceiveMessage from SQS": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Parameters": {
    "MaxNumberOfMessages": 1,
    "QueueUrl": "******"
  },
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sqs:receiveMessage",
  "Next": "Run Analysis Queries",
  "ResultSelector": {
    "body.$": "States.StringToJson($.Messages[0].Body)"
  }
},
"Run Analysis Queries": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Parameters": {
    "ClusterIdentifier": "******",
    "Database": "prod",
    "Sql": "select * from ******"
  },
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:redshiftdata:executeStatement",
  "ResultPath": "$.redshift_output",
  "Next": "delete_sqs"
},
"delete_sqs": {
  "Comment": "Deletes SQS message",
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sqs:deleteMessage",
  "Parameters": {
    "ReceiptHandle.$": "$.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle",
    "QueueUrl": "******"
  },
  "ResultPath": null,
  "Next": "update_result"
}
```

Also, you may read up to 10 messages at a time setting `MaxNumberOfMessages` equals `10` along with a Map step like in this example here:

```
{
    "StartAt": "read_sqs",
    "States": {
      "read_sqs": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sqs:receiveMessage",
        "Parameters": {
          "MaxNumberOfMessages": 10,
          "QueueUrl": "*******"
        },
        "ResultPath": "$.queueResponse",
        "Next": "check_results"
      },
      "check_results": {
        "Comment": "Checking if queue is empty",
        "Type": "Choice",
        "Choices": [
          {
            "Variable": "$.queueResponse.Messages[0]",
            "IsPresent": true,
            "Next": "map_results"
          }
        ],
        "Default": "exit"
      },
      "map_results": {
        "Comment": "Performs a 'map' operation over each payload",
        "Type": "Map",
        "ItemsPath": "$.queueResponse.Messages",
        "MaxConcurrency": 10,
        "Iterator": {
          "StartAt": "read_request",
          "States": {
            "read_request": {
              "Comment": "Parses and moves the request body into the response",
              "Type": "Pass",
              "Parameters": {
                "requestBody.$": "States.StringToJson($.Body)"
              },
              "ResultPath": "$.map_response",
              "Next": "Run Analysis Queries"
            },
            "Run Analysis Queries": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Parameters": {
                "ClusterIdentifier": "******",
                "Database": "prod",
                "Sql": "select * from ******"
              },
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:redshiftdata:executeStatement",
              "ResultPath": "$.redshift_output",
              "Next": "delete_sqs"
            },
            "delete_sqs": {
              "Comment": "Deletes SQS message",
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sqs:deleteMessage",
              "Parameters": {
                "ReceiptHandle.$": "$.ReceiptHandle",
                "QueueUrl": "*******"
              },
              "ResultPath": null,
              "End": true
            }
          }
        },
        "ResultPath": "$.flowResponse",
        "Next": "exit"
      },
      "exit": {
        "Type": "Pass",
        "End": true
      }
    }
  }
```